# assigning values from a map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I get a prop `view` from a parent component and based on that prop, I want to assign the `currentView` object from a map. But I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Suppose, if the `view` prop is **people** then when I console log `currentView` object, I should get the `peopleArray` and name to be **people world**.

```
export default {
  props: {
    view: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  watch: {
    view: {
      handler(val) {
        const viewOptions = {
          people: {
            array: this.peopleArray,
            name: 'People world',
          },
          robots: {
            array: this.robotArray,
            name: 'Robot world',
          },
        };
        this.currentView = viewOptions[val];
        console.log(this.currentView.array) //when I console log this, I want to get the peopleArray or robotArray
      },
    },
  },
  data(){
    return{
     peopleArray: ['Sam', 'Rob'],
     robotArray: ['Wall-E', 'R2D2'],
     currentView: {}
   }
 }
```

Comment: do you mean `this.currentView = viewOptions[val]`? .... does that fix it (what does the html look like)?

Comment: yup that was a typo, but not getting the correct output with the correct map variable either

Comment: what are you getting? can you provide more of a [mcve]? are you sure `val` is correct?

Comment: something like `{__ob__: Observer}
__ob__: Observer
dep: Dep
id: 1321
subs: []
[[Prototype]]: Object
value: {__ob__: Observer}
vmCount: 0
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: FWIW, this is solved with a computed in a simpler way

Comment: how would I solve this in computed property? @EstusFlask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `immediate: true` to your watcher:

```js
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: `
    <div class="">
      {{ currentView }}
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    view: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  watch: {
    view: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(val) {
        const viewOptions = {
          people: {
            array: this.peopleArray,
            name: 'People world',
          },
          robots: {
            array: this.robotArray,
            name: 'Robot world',
          },
        };
        this.currentView = viewOptions[val];
        immediate: true
        console.log(this.currentView.array) //when I console log this, I want to get the peopleArray or robotArray
      },
    },
  },
  data(){
    return{
     peopleArray: ['Sam', 'Rob'],
     robotArray: ['Wall-E', 'R2D2'],
     currentView: {}
   }
 },
})


new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      type: 'people'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.type === 'people' ? this.type = 'robots' : this.type = 'people'
      console.log(this.type)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="change">change</button>
  <child :view="type" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That property value depends on another value means this is the case for computed property:

```
computed: {
  currentView() {
     const viewOptions = {...};
     return viewOptions[this.view];
  }
  ...
```